# How to find the basis for eigenspace in $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone explain to me what is going on here?  I am following exercise where it says

> find the basis for  eigenspace in $\mathbb{C}^2$ where the matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}1&5\\-2&3\end{bmatrix}$

I got the eigenvalue $ 2\pm3i$ and then did $A - \lambda_1I = 0$ (where $\lambda = 2 + 3)$ to get $\begin{bmatrix}-1-3i&5\\-2&1-3i\end{bmatrix}$

but then the author says the basis vector for the eigen space is 
$v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1-3i\\2\end{bmatrix}$.. How do they get there?

I put the matrix in RREF to get

$R_2 = R_2/-2$

$R_2 = R_1 + (1+3i)R_2$

$R_2 = \frac{R_2}{5+\frac{(i-3i)^2}{-2}}$

$R_1 = -5R_2 + R_1$

$\begin{bmatrix}-1-3i&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: The first entry in $A-\lambda_1I$ should be $-1-3i$.

Comment: Typo @Moo , but I am still getting the same $rref(A)$ :(

Comment: @Yusha After your second step I get $\begin{bmatrix} -1-3i & 5 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ which is already in REF.

Comment: You don't even need use the matrix calculator: your first two steps are correct (except that you really should have separated your second step into two separate ones).  Go back through your calculations.

Comment: Oh I see now... now that I have $\begin{bmatrix}-1-3i&5\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ how can I find the eigenvectors? It's confusing. would I just do $\begin{bmatrix}(-1-3i)\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}-1+3i\\0\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Oh wait $x_2$ is free so it can be *any* number right?

Comment: so It would be like $\begin{bmatrix}1+3i\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1-3i\\1\end{bmatrix}$ right?

Comment: Remember that $$\begin{bmatrix}-1-3i&5\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$ really means $$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c} -1-3i&5 &0\\0&0 &0\end{array}\right] \iff\begin{cases}(-1-3i)x_1+5x_2=0 \\ 0 = 0\end{cases}$$  Let $x_2 = t$, then $x_1 = \frac{-5}{-1-3i}t$.  So your eigenvectors will be of the form $$t\begin{bmatrix} \frac{-5}{-1-3i} \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$ for all $t\in \Bbb C$.  To find *representative* eigenvectors, just choose your favorite $t$.  The author of your book takes $t=2$ (and then simplifies the first entry of the vector).

Comment: would the other vector then be $t \begin{bmatrix}\frac{-5}{-1+3i}\\1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: I feel confident you can figure that out for yourself.  Hint: A vector $v$ is an eigenvector of a matrix $A$ if $Av=\lambda v$ for some $\lambda\in\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteric polynomial of 
$
A=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 5 \\
-2 & 3
\end{array}\right]
$
is 
$$
\chi_A(t)=t^{2} - 4 t + 13
$$
The eigenvalues of $A$ are thus
$$
\frac{4\pm\sqrt{4^2-4(1)(13)}}{2}=2\pm3\,i
$$
Now, to compute a basis for the eigenspace $E_{2+3\,i}$, note that
$$
E_{2+3\,i}=\DeclareMathOperator{Null}{Null}\Null\bigl((2+3\,i)I-A\bigr)=\Null\left[\begin{array}{rr}
3 i + 1 & -5 \\
2 & 3 i - 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
We can row-reduce in two steps

- scale row 1 by $-3/10\,i + 1/10$
- add $-2$ times row 1 to row 2

This gives
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref\left[\begin{array}{rr}
3 i + 1 & -5 \\
2 & 3 i - 1
\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & \frac{3}{2} i - \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
Hence
$$
E_{2+3\,i}=\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}
\Span\{\langle -1+3\,i,2\rangle\}
$$
This also implies
$$
E_{2-3\,i}=\Span\{\langle-1-3\,i,2\rangle\}
$$